# Compare two forest loss classifications and fill missing years: accuracy assesment or correlation?

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, accuracy

I have a time series of forest loss rasters originating from two different classifications with some missing yearly data. Rasters represents forest loss (1) or no disturbance (0) in specific year. I think that one classification underestimates the other.

Example of time series (t1, t2.,,,) and missing years from one classification:

[image]

I am curious if there is a way to **compare the accuracy between overlapping years**, and based on this value calculate the "underestimation" between two classifications, and **forest loss values for missing years**?

I think I can calculate accuracy assessment for overlapping years, but maybe **some sort of raster correlation is better to predict forest loss values on missing years from class1, based on class2**?

My dummy example illustrates rasters from two classifications in one year, calculates the accuracy and the "underestimation" between both.

[image]

Dummy data (one year)

```
library(raster)

val1<-c(0,1,1,1,0,
           1,1,1,1,1,
           1,1,1,0,0,
           0,1,1,0,0,
           0,1,1,0,1)

val2<-c(0,1,1,1,0,
        1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,0,0,0,
        0,1,0,0,0,
        0,1,0,0,1)

r1<- raster(ncol = 5, nrow = 5)
r2<- raster(ncol = 5, nrow = 5)

values(r1)<-val1
values(r2)<-val2

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(r1, main = "r1:", legend = FALSE)
plot(r2, main = "r2:\nUnderestimate")

# Calculate error matrix
out<-table(val1, val2)


#       val2
# val1  0  1
#    0  9  0
#    1  3 13

# User accuracy
diag(out) /rowSums(out)

# Producer accuracy
diag(out)/colSums(out)

sums <- vector()

for(i in 1:dim(out)[1]){
  sums[i] <- out[i,i]

}

o.accuracy <- sum(sums)/sum(out)
```

What are your suggestions to **predict forest loss data for missing years for classification1 based on classification2**? Should I go by **accuracy assessemnt on overlapping years** or should I apply a correlation between rasters?